# Validation code (Unterminated string constant) in aspx

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I use VS 2012 and aspx pages.

I have this code:

```
                <input name="btnReservar" type="button" value='<%# "Reservar " + Eval("IDCURSO") %>'
                    onclick="window.open('<%# Common.Utility.RutaPortalAlumno 
                       + "DetalleCatalogoPre.aspx?idubicacion=" +  Common.Utility.IdUbicacion
                       + "&iddic=" + Common.Utility.IdDiccionario
                       + "&IdCurso=" + Eval("IDCURSO") + "&IdConvocatoria=" + Eval("IDCONVOCATORIA")
                       %>'); return false;" />
```

All is right in execution. It works just fine.

But Visual Studio give me warnings about that code, is not valid: **Unterminated string constant**.

Note: **DOCTYPE** is **XHTML 1.0 Transitional**

Any suggestions?

Comment: What does the generated html look like? Because when I tested your snippet (and replacing the Eval and Almagesto with my own) it works just fine.

Comment: @VDWWD right, in execution time, all works fine. Only are warning messages in Visual Studio about code validation.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe a bug? In VS 2017 pro there is no such warning.